# Code inside callbacks execute when screen rotates

Tags: android

I've had several instances of code inside a callback in Android executing when I rotate the screen.  I always test screen rotation because of this 'buggy' behaviour.  But today I thought maybe I am doing something wrong, or maybe this is a bug that should be reported to the Android project.

The latest example is this

I have an AutoCompleteField.

```
FindReplaceAutoCompleteAdapter mAutoCompleteAdapter;
protected void onCreate(...){
    mAutoCompleteAdapter = new FindReplaceAutoCompleteAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    mFindRule.setAdapter(mAutoCompleteAdapter);
}
```

I have the Adapter

```
public class FindReplaceAutoCompleteAdapter extends
        ArrayAdapter<FindReplaceRuleContainer> {

    private FindReplaceRuleFilter mFilter = null;

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        if (mFilter == null)
            mFilter = new FindReplaceRuleFilter();
        return mFilter;
    }

    public FindReplaceAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context,
            int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

}
```

And the filter

```
public class FindReplaceRuleFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults fr = null;
        if (constraint != null) {
            List<FindReplaceRuleContainer> list = getFilterdValues(constraint
                    .toString());

            if (list != null) {
                fr = new FilterResults();
                fr.values = list;
                fr.count = list.size();
            }
        }
        return fr;
    }

    private List<FindReplaceRuleContainer> getFilterdValues(String string) {
        List<FindReplaceRuleContainer> lst = Sdbi
                .loadFindReplaceRulesAutoComplete(FindReplaceList.this,
                        string);
        return lst;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {
        /**
         * Publish the result to the list activity so it looks pretty.
                     * Instead of a drop-down list
         */
        mAutoCompleteAdapter.clear();
        if( Adapter != null ){ //this is the fix I had to do because 
                     //this code is called even though no filter action was launched
                     //It crashes because the Adapter is reloaded on an AsyncTask that
                     //start onResume() and may not be done by the time this code
                     //inexplicably resides to run
            Adapter.clear();
            if (results != null) { 
            ...
            }
            Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

The code in publishResults() is called as I rotate the screen after onResume().
But the AutoComplete field is not even touched as the screen rotates.

This behavior can be seen on other UI components, but I failed to record the other instances.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm having the same issue.